# Unity shader that make overlapped regions transparent?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

[image]

Say i have two planes, i wanna know how to write shader that make overlapped region transparent.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stencil shader does exactly what you want in **opposite** way. Perhaps you could adapt it to your problem.

Here it is: https://youtu.be/xkcCWqifT9M?t=218
And documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html
This one is exciting as well: https://youtu.be/l7LQmJuoiBY?t=940

Comment: Exactly what im looking for! (Especially 3rd link) Thanks alot!